# @RequestBody working with String but not working with pojo model Rest Web Service

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jackson

Why the service below works perfectly if I use String as parameter but it doesn't work with model class. I didn't get error at all but it allways receives null if I use a model instead of String. Note: I do have mvc:annotation-driven in mvc-dispatcher-servelet and alls Jackson libraries. My guess is that I have somethng wrong with the libraries because it was running correctly before I changed the application from Spring 3 to Spring 4. Please, could some check if I need something else in POM?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/log")
public class Lo_Controller {
       @RequestMapping(value="display/last2", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
       @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
       @ResponseBody
       //after taking out @ModelAtribute I don't reach this method when debugging
       public String getTest(@RequestBody Mas60010b mas60010b) { //if I change Mas60010b mas60010b to String strTest ...
              Lo_Mas60010 lo_Mas60010 = new Lo_Mas60010();
              System.out.println(mas60010b.getSubCd()); 
              //System.out.println(strTest); //... it will work
              return "returnTestPost";
       }
```

Model:

```
public class Mas60010b {
       private String subCd;
       private String firstDT;
       private String currDT;

       public String getSubCd() {
              return subCd;
       }

       public void setSubCd(String subCd) {
              this.subCd = subCd;
       }

       public String getFirstDT() {
              return firstDT;
       }

       public void setFirstDT(String firstDT) {
              this.firstDT = firstDT;
       }

       public String getCurrDT() {
              return currDT;
       }

       public void setCurrDT(String currDT) {
              this.currDT = currDT;
       }
```

The client tester

```
public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
              HttpClient client2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost post2 = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/MHE2/log/display/last2");
              Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
              map2.put("subCd", "A");                 
              map2.put("firstDT", "2014-09-29 00:00:00.0");
              map2.put("currDT", "2014-09-30 16:45:33.379731");

              ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();
              String strJson2 = mapper2.writeValueAsString(map2);
              StringEntity input2 = new StringEntity(strJson2);

              input2.setContentType("application/json");
              post2.setEntity(input2);

              //Without @ModelAtribute I get [WARNING ] SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.
              HttpResponse response2 = client2.execute(post2);

              BufferedReader rd2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response2.getEntity().getContent()));

              String line2 = "";

              while ((line2 = rd2.readLine()) != null) {

                     System.out.println(line2);

              }

       }

}
```

Effective Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>MHE2</groupId>

  <artifactId>MHE2</artifactId>

  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>MHE Maven Webapp</name>

  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>

    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>

    <spring.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>

    <java-version>1.6</java-version>

    <jackson.databind-version>2.2.3</jackson.databind-version>

    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>

      <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>

      <version>1.0</version>

      <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>

      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>

      <version>4.3.3</version>

      <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>

      <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>

      <version>4.3.3</version>

      <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>

      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>

      <version>2.5</version>

      <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>

      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>

      <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>

      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>

      <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>

      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>

      <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>

      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>

      <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>

      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>

      <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>

      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>

      <scope>compile</scope>

      <exclusions>

        <exclusion>

          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>

          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>

        </exclusion>

      </exclusions>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>

      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>

      <version>1.1.1</version>

      <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>

      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>

      <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>

      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>

      <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <repositories>

    <repository>

      <snapshots>

        <enabled>false</enabled>

      </snapshots>

      <id>central</id>

      <name>Central Repository</name>

      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>

    </repository>

  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>

    <pluginRepository>

      <releases>

        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>

      </releases>

      <snapshots>

        <enabled>false</enabled>

      </snapshots>

      <id>central</id>

      <name>Central Repository</name>

      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>

    </pluginRepository>

  </pluginRepositories>

  <build>

    <sourceDirectory>C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\src</sourceDirectory>

    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>

    <testSourceDirectory>C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>

    <outputDirectory>C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes</outputDirectory>

    <testOutputDirectory>C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>

    <resources>

      <resource>

        <directory>C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\src</directory>

        <excludes>

          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>

        </excludes>

      </resource>

    </resources>

    <testResources>

      <testResource>

        <directory>C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\src\test\resources</directory>

      </testResource>

    </testResources>

    <directory>C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\target</directory>

    <finalName>MHE2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>

      <plugins>

        <plugin>

          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>

          <version>1.3</version>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>

          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>

          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>

          <version>2.8</version>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>

          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>

          <version>2.3.2</version>

        </plugin>

      </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>

      <plugin>

        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

        <version>3.1</version>

        <executions>

          <execution>

            <id>default-testCompile</id>

            <phase>test-compile</phase>

            <goals>

              <goal>testCompile</goal>

            </goals>

            <configuration>

              <source>1.6</source>

              <target>1.6</target>

            </configuration>

          </execution>

          <execution>

            <id>default-compile</id>

            <phase>compile</phase>

            <goals>

              <goal>compile</goal>

            </goals>

            <configuration>

              <source>1.6</source>

              <target>1.6</target>

            </configuration>

          </execution>

        </executions>

        <configuration>

          <source>1.6</source>

          <target>1.6</target>

        </configuration>

      </plugin>

      <plugin>

        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>

        <version>2.4</version>

        <executions>

          <execution>

            <id>default-war</id>

            <phase>package</phase>

            <goals>

              <goal>war</goal>

            </goals>

            <configuration>

              <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>

            </configuration>

          </execution>

        </executions>

        <configuration>

          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>

        </configuration>

      </plugin>

      <plugin>

        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>

        <version>2.5</version>

        <executions>

          <execution>

            <id>default-clean</id>

            <phase>clean</phase>

            <goals>

              <goal>clean</goal>

            </goals>

          </execution>

        </executions>

      </plugin>

      <plugin>

        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>

        <version>2.4</version>

        <executions>

          <execution>

            <id>default-install</id>

            <phase>install</phase>

            <goals>

              <goal>install</goal>

            </goals>

          </execution>

        </executions>

      </plugin>

      <plugin>

        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>

        <version>2.6</version>

        <executions>

          <execution>

            <id>default-resources</id>

            <phase>process-resources</phase>

            <goals>

              <goal>resources</goal>

            </goals>

          </execution>

          <execution>

            <id>default-testResources</id>

            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>

            <goals>

              <goal>testResources</goal>

            </goals>

          </execution>

        </executions>

      </plugin>

      <plugin>

        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>

        <version>2.12.4</version>

        <executions>

          <execution>

            <id>default-test</id>

            <phase>test</phase>

            <goals>

              <goal>test</goal>

            </goals>

          </execution>

        </executions>

      </plugin>

      <plugin>

        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>

        <version>2.7</version>

        <executions>

          <execution>

            <id>default-deploy</id>

            <phase>deploy</phase>

            <goals>

              <goal>deploy</goal>

            </goals>

          </execution>

        </executions>

      </plugin>

      <plugin>

        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>

        <version>3.3</version>

        <executions>

          <execution>

            <id>default-site</id>

            <phase>site</phase>

            <goals>

              <goal>site</goal>

            </goals>

            <configuration>

              <outputDirectory>C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\target\site</outputDirectory>

              <reportPlugins>

                <reportPlugin>

                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>

                </reportPlugin>

              </reportPlugins>

            </configuration>

          </execution>

          <execution>

            <id>default-deploy</id>

            <phase>site-deploy</phase>

            <goals>

              <goal>deploy</goal>

            </goals>

            <configuration>

              <outputDirectory>C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\target\site</outputDirectory>

              <reportPlugins>

                <reportPlugin>

                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>

                </reportPlugin>

              </reportPlugins>

            </configuration>

          </execution>

        </executions>

        <configuration>

          <outputDirectory>C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\target\site</outputDirectory>

          <reportPlugins>

            <reportPlugin>

              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>

            </reportPlugin>

          </reportPlugins>

        </configuration>

      </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>

  <reporting>

    <outputDirectory>C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\target\site</outputDirectory>

  </reporting>

</project>
```

Log from WebSphere 8.5 Liberty profile

```
[WARNING ] Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [bundleresource://96.fwk327208746/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system

URL [bundleresource://96.fwk327208746/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: bundleresource://96.fwk327208746/

[WARNING ] Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [bundleresource://95.fwk327208746/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system

URL [bundleresource://95.fwk327208746/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: bundleresource://95.fwk327208746/

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\db2java.jar] because it does not denote a directory

[WARNING ] Skipping [C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.12.jar] because it does not denote a directory
```

...
    [WARNING ] Skipping [C:\Users\e049447.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.1.2.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory

```
[WARNING ] SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.

[12/3/14 8:55:38:812 CST] 0000001a ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [bundleresource://96.fwk327208746/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system

java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [bundleresource://96.fwk327208746/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: bundleresource://96.fwk327208746/

                at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:212)

                at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52)

                at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:212)
```

...

```
[12/3/14 8:55:39:470 CST] 0000001a b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping I Mapped "{[/log/display/last2],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.mastercard.mhe.common.controller.Lo_Controller.getTest(com.mastercard.mhe.log.domain2.Mas60010b)

[12/3/14 8:55:39:782 CST] 0000001a b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter I Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Dec 03 08:55:37 CST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext

[12/3/14 8:55:40:063 CST] 0000001a b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter I Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Dec 03 08:55:37 CST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext

[12/3/14 8:55:40:267 CST] 0000001a .springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping I Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'

[12/3/14 8:55:40:313 CST] 0000001a org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet            I FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 2548 ms

[12/3/14 8:55:40:313 CST] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [MHE_original] [/MHE2] [mvc-dispatcher]: Initialization successful.

[12/3/14 8:55:40:470 CST] 00000022 SystemOut                                                    O null

[12/3/14 8:56:29:485 CST] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt                                  W SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.
```

Comment: I don't think you should be using `@RequestBody` and `@ModelAttribute` together. Try using just RequestBody to see if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Bohuslav has said in their comment, `@RequestBody` and `@ModelAttribute` must not be used on the same method parameter.  Remove `@ModelAttribute` and then try again.  After that your model parameter will be populated correctly.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your comment. I tried removing @ModelAttribute but now I get "[WARNING ] SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed" when calling from client. I added my effective pom. I give a try by taking out the jackson libraries from pom and pasted it in web-inf/lib and add them manually instead of using maven but I am still facing this warnning. I tried it because I can see that the problem only happens when sending a map to a model. Something might be wrong with pom because this web service was working correctly before I converted this project to maven.

Comment: I took your code, created a [sample project](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-mvc-mhe) and tried it on my machine.  The project works just fine.  Just download it to your machine and then run it as `mvn clean tomcat7:run`.  Then, use an AJAX client like the Postman extension for Chrome to submit a JSON request to `http://localhost:8080/log`.  You should see the submitted information back.  I made some minor changes to the POM - 1. `<scope>compile</scope>` is not required. 2. Servlet API must have scope `provided`.  You can generate a WAR and deploy to other app servers and try.

Comment: thank you so much. Because you told me that my code was correct and you runned it in Tomcat I started to focus in Websphere Liberty Profile configuration and I changed the server.xml by adding json feature. I don't know every thing envolved in it but certainly it was something related to this feature configuration. For future readers, this is the end of my server.xml
<featureManager>
<feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
<feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
<feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
<feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
<feature>json-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
...plus extra datasource configs

Comment: Great! WebSphere is always a pain to get up and running correctly.